# Excel: Set Text Colour of result in Excel formula

Tags: excel-formula

Excel: Is it possible to set the text colour of a result of a formula within the formula code?

Comment: No, you can use conditional formatting.  Formulas by there nature will return a result but not change the format of a cell.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this with the use of a helper cell or VBA code.  Conditional formatting can colour based on the result of a cell matching a value, being in a rage etc or even if you want to format it according to a formula.  Conditional formatting also does not have to be based on the cell it is applied to but could be based on the value from other cells.

So as Scott said, not in the formula itself, but there are other ways to automatically colour code based n values.